# PicketLink ClassNotFoundException org.picketlink.Identity on deployment to WildFly

Tags: java, eclipse, wildfly, picketlink

I want to use the PicketLink APIs in a web application on a WildFly server. I tried to use the PicketLink Quickstart ["picketlink-authorization-idm-jpa"](https://github.com/jboss-developer/jboss-picketlink-quickstarts/tree/master/picketlink-authorization-idm-jpa) as a basic implementation and enhance it for my needs. But always when deploying the (unmodified) application to my server I get a `ClassNotFoundException org.picketlink.Identity` and I don't know how to resolve it. Did someone have the same problem and found a solution for that? I'm using Eclipse Mars and the JBoss WildFly server 8.2.0 and 9.0.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve the problem by myself by changing the PicketLink-dependency from 2.8.0.Beta1-SNAPSHOT to 2.7.0.Final. I accidentally used 2.7.0.Final-SNAPSHOT before which also didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't faced this issue before , but you may try the below solutions

1) Try adding dependencies,here it might be picketlink-core-**.jar in MANIFEST.MF
2) if (1) doesn't work try adding jboss-deployment-structure.xml

Comment: the containing file is picketlink-api-2.7.0.Final.jar. Unfortunately both ways don't work for me, still getting the same error.